# Using 256 colour themes not working in vim/putty

Tags: vim, putty, vimrc

PuTTY shows the the correct xterm-256color.
Colours section shows "Allow Terminal to specify ANSI colours" and "Allow terminal to use xterm-256-colour mode".

Yet when I use themes, they don't work, the themes all end up looking like variations of 'ron'

And my **.vimrc**

```
set t_Co=256
syntax on
color wombat
set autoindent
set cindent
set smartindent
set tabstop=3
set shiftwidth=3
set expandtab
```

`$ infocmp -1L xterm | grep max_colors`

**max_colors#256,**

`$ echo $TERM`

**xterm-256color**

`$ tput colors`

**256**

Any ideas on how to fix this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colorscheme also needs to support (high color) terminals. For the one referenced in your `~/.vimrc`, [wombat](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Wombat/blob/master/colors/wombat.vim), this one only supports the GUI (there are only `guifg=` / `guibg=` attributes).

There's a special version of wombat for 256-color xterm, [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2465).

#### Alternatives

Plugins like [CSApprox](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390) can take the GUI color definitions and convert them to a closely matching 256-color `cterm` color palette for high-color terminals. This helps with colorschemes that otherwise only pick from the bland default 16-color terminal color palette, or only provide GUI color definitions.

Another approach is taken by [csexact](https://github.com/KevinGoodsell/vim-csexact), which modifies the (supported) terminal's palette to exactly match Vim's GUI colors.

Comment: Ah I did not know there was a difference between GUI and standard 256 colour themes.  Thank you!  However, I did notice maybe it is a theme issue, or something else, but where the file ends, where all the tildes are, the dark grey background becomes black.

Comment: Thanks! The "tilde end" is the `NonText` highlight group, you can adapt it. The reason for the discrepancy might be the reduced number of available colors, i.e. a slightly off-black is impossible to achieve.